# Exact sequence with chain complexes

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology

Let $C_{\ast}$ be a chain complex and $p$ a prime. Is it true that $$0\rightarrow C_{\ast}\overset{\cdot p}{\rightarrow}C_{\ast}\overset{\pi}{\rightarrow}C_{\ast}/pC_{\ast}\rightarrow 0$$ is always an exact sequence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplication by $p$ is not necessarily injective Let $C_{\ast} = \dots \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \dots$, then $\cdot p$ is the zero map.

Comment: So is it not true. What does it mean that a chain map is injective?

Comment: I'd say it means that it is injective on each chain. Or equivalently, that $0 \rightarrow C_{\ast} \overset{f}{\rightarrow} D_{\ast}$ is exact.

Comment: @user372565: There are general definitions, but in the special case of chain maps of chain complexes, a chain map is monic if and only if the morphisms in each degree are monic.